# Pointer not showing updated value when incrementing a variable in std::cout

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-precedence

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  int& b = a;
  int* c = &a;

  cout << "CASE 1" << endl;
  cout << "a is " << a << endl << "b is " << b << endl << "c is " << *c << endl;
  b = 10;
  cout << endl << "a is " << a << endl << "b is " << b << endl << "c is " << *c << endl << endl;

  cout << "CASE 2";
  a = 5;
  cout << endl << "a is " << a << endl << "b is " << b << endl << "c is " << *c << endl;
  b = 10;
  cout << endl << "a is " << a << endl << "b is " << ++b << endl << "c is " << *c << endl << endl;

  cout << "CASE 3";
  a = 5;
  cout << endl << "a is " << a << endl << "b is " << b << endl << "c is " << *c << endl;
  b = 10;
  cout << endl << "a is " << a << endl << "b is " << b++ << endl << "c is " << *c << endl;
}
```

The output:

CASE 1:

```
a is 5. b is 5. c is 5.
a is 10. b is 10. c is 10.
```

CASE 2:

```
a is 5. b is 5. c is 5.

a is 11. b is 11. c is 10.
```

CASE 3:

```
a is 5. b is 5. c is 5.
a is 11. b is 10. c is 10.
```

I understand CASE 1. But I am having difficulty understanding CASE 2 and CASE 3. Can someone explain why doesn't `c` get updated with new value in both cases?

Comment: Can you add the output

Comment: It is undefined as to the order of operations of `<<`.  Simply put, `operator <<` is a function, and those are its arguments.  Arguments to a function can be evaluated in any order, as it is implementation defined.

Comment: Looks like undefined and/or unspecified behaviour. Perhaps even depending on which standard version of C++ is being used. The rules for sequencing and operator precedence are almost hopelessly complicated, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence. My personal rule to stay clear from all that trouble is to never access an object to which `++` is applied in the same expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The evaluation order of operands is unspecified, and you're modifying an object and reading it without those operations being sequenced.

Thus, your program is as undefined as `cout << a << a++;`, and anything can happen.

Comment: This is a bit vague. "Anything can happen" makes it look like it has Undefined Behavior, but it's only true if using old C++ (before C++11). "As undefined as ..." is correct but not helpful; I believe it's actually "UB in C++03; unspecified in C++11 and later" for both code in OP and `cout << a << a++`. I am not sure though.

Comment: @anatolyg Operand evaluations are unsequenced in C++11 (§1.9, item 15), leading to undefined behaviour. I believe 17 changes this.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is due to what is called **sequence points**. You can have a long read about that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/1485885) but in a few words it basically states the order or evaluation of the elements of an expression.

**Update** in your case this order is undefined, although some compilers seem to make it right-to-left.